# Rails 3: How to format a Date in other than English languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, date-formatting

To format a `Date` in English I do:

```
Date.today.to_s(:long_ordinal)   # => September 28th, 2011
```

How could I format a date in Russian (or any other language) ?

Comment: Maybe explain the exact format you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Internationalization API in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) that explains how to do that. See for example section 3.2 Adding Date/Time Formats.

```
<p><%= l Date.today, :format => :short %></p>
```

You can then add for your locale (russian?) a file `ru.yml` and include there the definition for your format.

```
# config/locales/ru.yml
ru:
  date:
    formats:
      short: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

See the section 4.4 Setting and Passing a Locale how to set the locale.

Comment: These guys have a good collection that might be useful: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Answer (score 1):

Date formats and locales are defined in ActiveSupport. You can add [these values](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml) to your locale file and modify them to fit your requirements.
Also check [this](https://github.com/dima4p/no_russian_gem/blob/master/config/locales/ru.yml) for russian language.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392). Example:

```
Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

You set the %-symbols according to how you want the date to format. See the documentation I linked to see what symbols you can use.

Comment: I couldn't find there any useful information about formatting in non-English languages.