# Rails/Ruby - Format string into Date with locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Is there a way in rails with localize or in plain ruby with Date.strptime to convert a string into a date but with a specific months locales?

For example, I have the following string -> `'5 abr 19'` where `abr == april` but in spanish, and I need it to convert it to a Date object.

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579153/rails-3-how-to-format-a-date-in-other-than-english-languages) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the date month in english, you can use Date.strptime with this format:

```
date_str = '5 apr 19'
date = Date.strptime(date_str, '%d %b %y')
```

Since that method only accepts english I would just translate the month, only a few months changes:

```
date_str = '5 abr 19'

months = {'ene' => 'jan', 'abr' => 'apr', 'ago' => 'aug', 'dic' => 'dec'}    
date_str_aux = date_str.gsub(/ene|abr|ago|dic/, months) # only replace the months that should be translated

date = Date.strptime(date_str_aux, '%d %b %y')
```

Comment: So I guess this is the only option I have left. I will go with this approach. Thanks!